# IntelliJ: automatically add current project-version to new class's comment

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I currently use an IntelliJ file header where I manually edit the `@since` tag with the current project-version as defined in maven's pom.xml, so that every newly created class is tagged with the first version it affected.
Is there a way to automatically extract that project version from maven and access it by a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is no. IntelliJ has a fixed set of variables that are available on the code template. You can define new variables, but you have to [hardcode the value or intellij will ask you on each file creation to enter a value](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/file-template-variables.html#custom_template_variables). And you cannot open a properties/xml file from a velocity template.

There's an alternative to write your own intellij plugin that makes the version variable available to the code templates.

You could try to re-purpose this intellij plugin which does something very similar: https://github.com/vkravets/FileTemplatesVariable

Comment: thx for the link. writing my own plugin seems like a good way to go : )

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit tricky solution for your problem:

1) add an include that is called like your maven project to the general "File Header.java" include in the IDEA File and Code Templates

[File Header.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtwJx.png)

2) create the include file that is called like your maven project (maybe with a file extension *.version like in my example) and add your project version as content:

[include example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YwMD.png)

3) use maven plugins to update the content of this file in your file system with the maven project version variable

There may be some other solutions by using the apache velocity engine.